# Dynamic Web table multiple checkbox selection for matching column value

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have application where there is a dynamic web table, I want to select multiple check box for matching value in one of column.

Refer attached image:

[image: Webapp snap]

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
List<WebElement> Rows = s.findElements((By.xpath("//a[text()='Nitesh Kumar']")));
System.out.println("No of rows = "+Rows.size());
int z=Rows.size();
int i =0; for(i=0;i<z;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Rows.size(); j++ )
    {
        s.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Nitesh Kumar']/../../td[1]")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<WebElement> Rows = s.findElements((By.xpath("//a[text()='Nitesh Kumar']")));
  System.out.println("No of rows = "+Rows.size());
  int z=Rows.size();
  int i =0;
  for(i=0;i<z;i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < Rows.size(); j++ )
   {
    s.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Nitesh Kumar']/../../td[1]")).click();
   }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Change the xpath to

```
//table[@id='id of the table']/tbody/*/td[3]/a[text()='Nitesh Kumar')]
```

to find the elements from the table.
Once the elements are found get the size of the list and use the below xpath to click the check box

```
//table[@id='id of the table']/tbody/*/td[3]/a[text()='Nitesh Kumar')]../td[1]
```

The complete code would be something like below.

```
List<WebElement> Rows = s.findElements((By.xpath("//table[@id='id of the table']/tbody/*/td[3]/a[text()='Nitesh Kumar')]")));
System.out.println("No of rows = "+Rows.size());
int z=Rows.size();
int i =0; 
for(i=0;i<z;i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < Rows.size(); j++ )
     {
        s.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='id of the table']/tbody/*/td[3]/a[text()='Nitesh Kumar')]../td[1]")).click();
     }
  }
```